# Enthalpy and its definiton

Tags: thermodynamics

I read books and i searched in internet to get what enthalpy is. It is equal to sum of internal energy and energy to keep its environment constant for movement.  It is 
    $ H=U+PV $  . But i found that it does not include p-v work. But H has in differential form $ dH=dU+PdV $. Here PdV must be p-v work. I am confused with these terms. What really enthalpy is and what is that it does not include p-v work?

Comment: H is a physical property of the material, irrespective of any process the material is being subjected to.  W is a characteristic of a process, irrespective of  the properties of the material that is being processed.  Also, your math needs some improvement:  dH=dU+PdV+**VdP**

Comment: Yes it right.  But i asked by keeping in mind that it is isobaric one.

Comment: Still, I maintain that H is a physical property of a material, irrespective of any process (i.e., work and/or heat) that the material is subjected to.  It is an equilibrium thermodynamic property, depending only on the present T, P, and V.  The sum of the individual enthalpies of the materials comprising a system is equal to the total enthalpy of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider heating a gas.

The heat (energy) that you put into the gas is equal to $\Delta H$

The increase in the internal energy of the gas is equal to $\Delta U$

And if the gas expands as you heat it then the gas does work - let us assume that this is at constant pressure $P$ -- the work done is $P \Delta V$

Conservation of energy means $\Delta H= \Delta U+P \Delta V $, which for s very small change can be written as $ dH=dU+PdV $.

So if a gas is heated at constant pressure the enthalpy delivered $\Delta H$ will partly heat the gas and partly do p-v work.

If a gas is heated at constant volume then the enthalpy delivered $\Delta H$ will only increase the internal energy of the gas because $\Delta V =0$.

So the enthalpy required to heat gas at constant volume is less than at constant pressure because p-v work will be done when heating at constant pressure.

I hope this helps to figure out what enthalpy is. - I think $\Delta H$ can be summarized as the energy required for a process to happen (or if it is negative the energy released when a process happens).

Comment: This means that entalpy is toatal energy supplied or total energy given out, right?

Comment: Is it similar to energy represented by Q in first law of thermodynamics? $ U=Q-W $ ?

Comment: @SrivishnuBharat yes for  toatal energy supplied or total energy given out, right

Comment: @SrivishnuBharat Yes it is similar to $Q$ - but it can be applied more widely... e.g. for chemical changes

Comment: Another way to look at enthalpy is the energy required to create your system from nothing. You need to supply the energy of the system (U) as well as the energy needed to push the atmosphere out of the way (PV)